# Rally allows creating duplicate test case with the same name

Tags: api, rally

We use Rally API (v 2.0) for automation of test case creation. Currently Rally allows duplicate creation of test folders & test cases with the same name within the same folder hierarchy.

Is there a way to not allow duplication of test case in the same folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.  We never have unique constraints on naming of objects.  If that is important to your use case you will need to implement these validations in your integration code.